# Difficulty Finding Tables in a Word Document using 'python-docx' library

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

*Hello World,*
I am working on a Python script using the *'python-docx'* library to process a *Micrasoft Word* document.
My goal is to find a specific paragraph and check if there is a table immediately below these paragraph. However, I'm encountering an issue where my code does not seem to find the table.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

I have a Word document (my_document.docx) with a structure similar to the following:

1. Text

[Table 1]

2. Some text

[Table 2]

3. More text

[Table 3]

I have succesfuly located the text inside the document, and now I want check if there is a table right below it (in this case, "Table 1"). If so, I need to perform certain operations on that table. However, my code does not identify the tables, and I'm unsure why.

Code Sample:

```
for i, paragraph in enumerate(my_document.paragraphs):
    if text_to_be_found == paragraph.text:
        # Check if there is something at position i + 1 to avoid 'index out of range' error
        if i + 1 < len(my_document.paragraphs):
            # Check if the element at position i + 1 is a table
            if my_document.paragraphs[i + 1]._element.tag.endswith('tbl'):
                # Do something with the table
```

My code does not correctly identify tables, and I'm not sure what condition to use in place of "???" to check if there's a table immediately below the paragraph.

I'm also unsure if I need to consider namespaces (e.g., 'w:tbl') when checking for tables.

I would like assistance in modifying my code to accurately identify tables that follow a specific text (paragraph) in the Word document.